# Video content blocked. Work around inside company?

Tags: video, intranet

We run a learning portal for people in IT institution. But the problem is video contents types are blocked in most institutions.

Is there anyway we will able to allow or by-pass the firewall so that users can view our video content?

- Our videos are hosted in Vimeo.
- We also track users and the videos watched by them.

Comment: Please do not post questions about circumventing policies and systems managed by our colleagues. You should speak to the appropriate people and ask them to remove any filters for your particular videos.

Comment: @Dan Not sure that applies. This is a company asking for approaches - there can be technical reasons (youtube blocked -use your own servers) or an approac to work WITH compliance (such as my answer - provide documentation what exactly is needed so customers can point their IT department for that). This is not a "How do I bypass my employers policies" but a "how can I work despite company policies when we want them as customers" type of question.

Comment: The Video Streaming as a whole is blocked. So it is of no-use to allow Vimeo by IT Admin (as it will not work)

Answer (score 4):

If your product has value then the people buying it will have to arrange within their organisation to have the necessary permissions.

What this means for you is you should be clear about what the requirements are for you to deliver the service.

Comment: The 2nd sentence seals it.  OP should clearly line out what a customer needs in order to access their content.  If the company is willing to pay for the content, they should realize what will be needed to access it.

Comment: The IT department are willing to talk and find a solution.

Comment: The problem is, they have strict rule in blocking all video streams. If they enable a platform(say Vimeo), employees may abuse and may also watch other videos on Vimeo

Comment: @siva: That's a management problem, not a technical one and as such is off topic here.

Comment: @lain : Hmm.. We need a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

No. Especially not reliably.

If you stream by HTTP then - HTTPS may work. Unless a proxy is employed, the content of a HTTPS stream are invisible to the firewall. It may block the hosts, but not by content type.

But otherwise - no. THIs is a problem, and your best chance is some isntructions for the admins how to unlock it (hosts etc.) so that the customers can point their IT-Depoartments to that.